# Omitting the subject of a sentence after 'em dash'(—)

Tags: subjects, em-dash

Can we omit the subject of a sentence  after  'em dash'(—).

If it is possible, then which option of the options below in formal writing is preferable?

***Examples***

option 1:

> These old cars are fixed by the master—in other words, they are renewed.

or option 2 (omitting 'they');

> These old cars are fixed by the master—in other words, are renewed.

Comment: Both your options are fine, as would be *These old cars are fixed by the master—in other words, **these old cars are** renewed* AND *—in other words, **renewed***. It's entirely a stylistic choice how many of those "predictably repeated" words you decide to "delete" from the *second* place where they are / would be used (and that's regardless of whether the repeated terms are nouns, verbs, or whatever - *everything* can potentially be deleted in such contexts).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both option 1 and option 2 are acceptable. The repeated subject "they" in option 1 (which refers back to "these old cars") can be omitted and will be understood by the reader.

This is not because of the dash, the same would be true if a comma were used instead.

In this case I would prefer option 1, it is slightly clearer at the cost of only a single word. But that is purely a matter of style, not grammar.

Comment: I'm afraid the OP's question is about formal writing, not grammar. Consequently, I would [definitely](https://www.theenglishbureau.com/blog/omitting-the-subject/) use the complete option, but that's just me.

Comment: Upvote Lucian's comment (I accidentally unvoted it)